Would you have made the alignment?
Would you have made the alignment with those specs? Fells like I'm getting scammed... 2nd in 4 months


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this the pre or post alignment report?

Pre alignment. I've seen some cars with worst specs after alignment...

Considering this is a pre-alignment, I'd get it done just because if you don't, your steering wheel will always be at a slant. That would drive me nuts. The second thing is, with it like it is, there's no toe-in, which means it would be hard to drive. Is the alignment necessary? IMHO, absolutely.
